# how to subtract two DateTime field in django model and keep the subtracted value in another field in same model?

Tags: python, django

```
class Attendance(EmployeFields):
    employee_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    login_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    logoff_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    hours_per_day = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I need to subtract logoff_date and login_date and put the value to hours_per_day while importing the date  to this model. i am importing the data for this model which have entries for both login_date and logoff_date .

i have tried to do like this but the function itself was not calling.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,update_fields=None):
    if self.login_date and self.logoff_date:
        logger.info(self.logoff_date)
        self.hours_per_day = (self.logoff_date - self.login_date).seconds // 3600
    else:
        self.hours_per_day = 0
    return super(Attendance, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

Comment: Don't save this value in the database, instead have this as a property on your model class.

Comment: i need to save this in database, that is a requirement. later on i need to fetch this hours_per_day field from database to do some other calculations. @ Abdul Aziz Barkat

Comment: You can use annotations to calculate this in the database itself. Storing attributes that can be calculated in the database is simply unnecessary trouble, later on one always needs to remember to update them when one updates one or the other field used to calculate this.

Comment: These values of login and logoff are imported from csv file, each time importing, the data present in the table will be flushed, so there is no problem with value updating or data redundancy.  I need to save in the database anyhow.

Comment: how about using signal?

Answer (score 0):

Once try this

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
        employee_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        login_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
        logoff_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
        hours_per_day = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.login_date and self.logoff_date:
                self.hours_per_day = (self.logoff_date - self.login_date).seconds // 3600
            else:
                self.hours_per_day = 0
            super(Attendance, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```